# how to add bulk update function in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bulk

I have a product catalogue where I'm building a way to track inventory. I created an Inventory controller and I want to list all products with text field to update product quantity for each.
Here is what I have for now

```
class InventoryController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @products = Product.all
  end
```

In my view

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <li>
    <%= product.name%> <%= product.in_stock %> 
      <%= form_for(product) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :in_stock %>
      <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Update" %>
```

First, I don't know if the code in the view is the right approach. Then, all the bulk_update logic is missing and have no clue how to proceed and make it Db efficient.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railscasts has various episodes on the the subject. Check #198 and search for 'edit multiple'